# Area of shapes in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I have a function called the_rectangle that I run twice to create two rectangles. However, I want python to figure out the Area's of each rectangle and determine which is bigger by printing ("The bigger rectangle's area is: )
and then printing ("The smaller rectangle's area is: ). Also I want it to use the arguments width and length to find the value of each area. Is this possible?

```
import turtle
import math


def the_rectangle(width, length, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def main():
    the_rectangle(200, 100, "red")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.pendown()
    the_rectangle(100, 250, "yellow")

main()
```

Comment: why don't you implement a function in which you pass the width and the height, and you determine the area of the rectangle. Later, you could call this function to see which rectangle is greater. Also, what version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your rectangle a class. That way you have all your data in one place.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, color): # Initialization
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, turtle): # Draws the rectangle
        turtle.color(color)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()

    def area(self): # Calculates the area
         return self.length * self.width
```

To use this class to compare areas, simply use the below code.

```
def main():
    rectangle1 = Rectangle(200, 100, "red")
    a1 = rectangle1.area()
    rectangle2 = Rectangle(100, 250, "yellow")
    a2 = rectangle2.area()

    print("The bigger rectangle's area is:", str(max(a1, a2)))
    print("The smaller rectangle's area is:", str(min(a1, a2)))

    # Draw the rectangles
    rectangle1.draw()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.pendown()
    rectangle2.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine which rectangle is bigger, then storing the rectangle (or its area) is going to be paramount. You could calculate the area before or after the rectangle is drawn, based on dimensions:

```py
# This will allow you to create a rectangle and store its area
# as a three-element tuple
def area(l, w):
    # returns a three-element tuple to represent a rectangle
    return (l, w, l*w)
```

Now, you can take the rectangle you return, and draw it. I'd unpack the dimensions using argument unpacking with `*`, and then you know you will just duplicate the length and width to draw it, lessening the amount of extra code you have to write:

```py
def draw_rectangle(*dimensions, color="red"):
    dims = dimensions[:2]*2 # creates a list [l, w, l, w]
    for dim in dims:
        turtle.forward(dim)
        turtle.left(90)
```

Now, to compare a rectangle, one is truly bigger than another if its area is larger, and therefore you can take any number of rectangles and pair them using `itertools.combinations`. Then you compare each pair and you can print the results out:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def compare_recs(*rectangles):
    for r1, r2 in combinations(rectangles, 2):
        # The third element of your tuple, denoted by the index [2],
        # is your area, which is what you are comparing against here
        bigger, smaller = (r1, r2) if r1[2] >= r2[2] else (r2, r1)
        print(f"The bigger rectangle is {bigger}")
        print(f"The smaller rectangle is {smaller}")

r1 = area(10, 20)
r2 = area(10, 15)
draw_rectangle(*r1, color='red')
draw_rectangle(*r2, color='yellow')


compare_recs(r1, r2)
The bigger rectangle is (10, 20, 200)
The smaller rectangle is (10, 15, 150)
```

You could do this with classes, but I think this is a fair place to start if you're new with Python.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish what you want, but the simplest modification to your existing code may be to have "the_rectangle" return the area.
You need to get the returned value and calculate the max/min area.

If you want to make this a larger-scale program, you'll need to go to creating classes, like mentioned in the other answers.

```
import turtle
import math


def the_rectangle(width, length, color):
    # This function draws a rectangle and returns the area
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    return width*length

def main():
    area_1 = the_rectangle(200, 100, "red")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.pendown()
    area_2 = the_rectangle(100, 250, "yellow")
    print("Largest rectangle is " + str(max(area_1,area_2)))
    print("Smallest rectangle is " + str(min(area_1,area_2)))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update existing function `the_rectangle`, you can create a decorator function which will print the area of rectangle, this area can be saved and later used to compare with other rectangle's area to check which is smaller and which is larger.

This is the sample code:

```
def area(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Area of rectangle %d*%d is: %d' % (args[0], args[1], args[0]*args[1]))
        return function(*args)
    return wrapper

@area
def the_rectangle(width, length, color):
    ...
```